# Как передать значение массива произвольной длины в качестве аргумента конструктора?

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация

Ну вот например я хочу сделать в своём типе данных так, чтобы я мог всунуть туда элементы массива:

`q_array arr {СЮДА};`

Вот примерно так:

`q_array arr {6161,61267,?12712,6126};`

Создаю свой тип данных похожий на вектор, для развития ;)

Ну вот допустим в конструкторе класса я могу сделать так: `q_array (Var, Var, Var);`

`Var` - если что это шаблон, можете считать, что это может быть любой тип данных выбранный юзером.

И получится что я могу написать:

`q_array arr {7,12712,616};` Я могу написать не больше и не меньше значений, т. к. выбрал только три аргумента, ну вот как сделать так, чтобы я мог написать столько значений массива, сколько у меня указано в шаблоне - 25?

Фуххххх спасибо, устал писать ;)

П. С. Это я пишу свой тип данных по типу вектора

Comment: раз пишете, будьте добры, покажите что написали

Answer (score 2):

Без проблем делается с использованием [`initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Например, вот такой [пример конкатенации строки](http://ideone.com/4OWqFc):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Concat
{
    string val;
    Concat(initializer_list<string> l)
    {
        for(auto s: l) val = val + s + " ";
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Concat c = { "Hello", "world" };
    cout << c.val << endl;
}
```

Думаю, для своих целей сможете переписать? :)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагают использовать `std::initializer_list`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
class MyVec
{
public:
    MyVec(std::initializer_list<Type> _list)
    {
        for(auto &it : _list)
        {
            m_vec.push_back(it);
        }
    }

    int size() const{
        return m_vec.size();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Type> m_vec;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    {
        MyVec<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
        std::cout << "Vec1 size:" << vec.size() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        MyVec<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        std::cout << "Vec2 size:" << vec.size() << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Простейшее решение которое приходит в голову

```
q_array(Type vl,...){ // Конструктор с параметрами переменной длинны
   va_list vl;
   va_start(vl,n);
     //...
   va_end(vl);
   }
// вызов
new q_array<int>(1,2,3);
```

Недостаток - куча push при работе массива.

Более сложное решение

```
  template <int N> q_array(Type (&x)[N]) {         
     ....
     }
 // А вызов так (для старого с++)
 int initializer[] = {1,2,3};
 new q_array(initializer); // возможно в с++17 можно упростить.
```

Comment: Второй вариант у меня не компилируется, говорит, что нужно указать размер массива. Компилятор C++14.

Comment: @markussie Да, пропустил размер массива. (у меня компилятор не ругался, странно)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно иметь массив конкретного размера? Тогда, например, так:

```
template <typename Var, unsigned N>
class q_array {
    std::unique_ptr<Var[]> array;
public:
    q_array(std::initializer_list<Var> list) 
        : array(new Var[N]) 
    // умный указатель на массив из N элементов
    {   
        auto It = list.begin();
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < N && i < list.size(); ++i)
             array[i] = *It++;
    }
    void show(std::ostream& out) const {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            out << array[i] << ' ';
    }
};

int main() { 
    q_array<int, 4> arr({ 4, 678, 44, 789, 6, 8 });
    //получим массив из первых 4 элементов списка 
    arr.show(std::cout);    
    return exec();
}
```